# An unhandled win32 exception occurred in pythonw.exe [11744]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crash

I am having a curious crash. I am using spyder 3.3.1 on Windows 7.
When running the following line:

```
df[cols]=df[cols].fillna(df.median())
```

Python crashes. I can choose to close the program or debug it. Choosing debug, the following appears:

[image: crash]

Spyder doesn't shut down but the kernel restarts (multiple times):

[image: kerneldied]

Problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  3.7.150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5b34dd6b
  Fault Module Name:    python37.dll
  Fault Module Version: 3.7.150.1013
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5b34dd15
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000002a0c1
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1030
  Additional Information 1: 923d
  Additional Information 2: 923de469bf7c9269a2f86708f66ec13b
  Additional Information 3: 823b
  Additional Information 4: 823b0533d10c72b7b59580188cafa7c2

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Any idea what could the cause be? How should I proceed to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Modifying the line:

```
df[cols]=df[cols].fillna(df.median())
```

to:

```
df[cols]=df[cols].fillna(df[cols].median())
```

Fixed the crash.

I then also managed to force an update to the latest available version of anaconda and tested that after the update the original code was working again. So whatever bug was causing the crash it has probably been already fixed.